# Matlab - Sparse Matrix system resolution

Tags: matlab, linear-algebra, sparse-matrix, markov-chains

I'm involved in the resolution of a system of the type `Ax = b`, where A is a square sparse matrix, x is the vector of the unknows (I have to compute it) and b is a vector of all zeros excpet for the last element which is a 1.
The last row of the matrix A is used for normalization, and so is fulfilled with ones.

The solutions of this system are probabilities and for this reason the condition `0<x(i)<1` must be respected.

In order to solve the system the Matlab command `x = A \ b;` is used.

The method seems to work well, but there is a special case in wich the vector x also contains negative values. Adding a very small value (10^-6) to any element of the Matrix A, the resolution back to meet the conditions.

I'm not a mathematician, so I don't know if it's a code problem, or if the matrix A must respect some properties to guarantee that the solutions are all between 0 and 1.

Comment: Are the negative values you get very small? How accurately is `Ax=b` satisfied by the resulting `x` (with its negative values) and is, e.g., `max(x,0)/sum(max(x,0))` (getting rid of them by brute force and fixing up the normalization) a better or a worse solution to `Ax=b`?

Comment: For what it's worth, I'd guess that this isn't an error in your code but a consequence of accumulated numerical errors. Solving large systems of equations is always subject to a bit of error. You may be able to improve the accuracy of a solution, at the cost of doing extra computation, by saying `x = A\b; x = x - A\(A*x-b);`; does that give you (1) a solution where `Ax-b` is smaller and/or (2) one where the negative elements are absent or less negative?

Comment: @Gareth Thanks for the reply, the negative values are in the order of 10^-3, so they cannot be neglected. I even tried your solution and: (1) the accuracy degrades, (2) the negative values are still there.

Comment: That's a shame. If the vector is (or is closely related to) the equilibrium probabilities for a Markov chain, and you have the matrix of transition probabilities (presumably something rather like A) then you're looking for solutions to Bx=x (or x=Bx, depending on which way around you write your transition matrices). If you have an approximate solution, and if the Markov chain is irreducible and aperiodic, then Bx will be a more accurate solution than x. (You might want to renormalize it.)

Comment: @Gareth So your suggestion is to switch the computation method from `Ax=b` to `x=Px`, where `P` is the transition probability matrix and `x` is the state probabilities vector. Am I rigth?

Comment: My suggestion is that you first solve `Ax=b` (perhaps giving a slightly inaccurate result) and then improve the solution by replacing `x` with `Px`. (Maybe more than once, if it helps but doesn't help enough.) Well, actually my suggestion is that you try it and see whether it's effective; I can't tell whether it actually will be for your application.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like what you really want is: minimize ||Ax-b|| subject to x > 0 for all x. You can do that with function lsqlin : http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/optim/ug/lsqlin.html

The 'must add to 1' is a linear equality constraint, positivity is a linear inequality constraint.

A related problem with probabilities in a matrix (not square) is this: http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/freeabs_all.jsp?arnumber=5717139